# Css Background Image and Text in new line

Tags: html, css

I am having problem with placing text below background image, I did play with CSS but no luck text is not moving to next line below image.

Here is my HTML

```
    <a class="bgimg">placing text below background image </a>
    .bgimg{
    background-image: url('images/HBR_compact_black_text_red_shield65x31.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
     }
```

I wanted to have background image at top and text below the image.

can anybody suggest me please ?

Comment: Make the anchor display block (with or without width depends on your design) then just add padding top to the anchor tag, assuming you want the entire thing to be clickable

Comment: Why not just use an `<img>` tag? http://jsfiddle.net/yhgw1krx/1/

Comment: @Huangism [**BAM!**](http://jsfiddle.net/7xm8wm92/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is in top padding, so you need:

```
padding-top: 20px;
```

Also, since it's an anchor which is inline by default, you need to set it to inline-block (setting it to block might cause text flow issues):

```
display: inline-block;
```

And that's it, see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2Log20b4/

Comment: @David, no answer is good enough without Mario in it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At that point, why not Just separate your elements a bit?

```
<div class="bgimg"></div>
<p>placing text below background image </p>

<style>
.bgimg{
background-image: url('images/HBR_compact_black_text_red_shield65x31.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width: 65px;
height: 31px;
}
</style>
```

the alternative would be to use text-align on your anchor (but you'd have to set the anchor to display as a block element first)

Answer (score 0):

If the `height` of the image is **unknown**, you could use [CSS generated content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) with a `url()` value as follows:

```css
.bgimg:before {
  content: url('http://placehold.it/100');
  display: block;
}
.bgimg {
  text-align: center; /* align the image to center */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="bgimg">
    placing text below background image
</a>
```

It's worth noting that generated content is supported in IE8 and newer.